# How to scale an image in only one direction in opengl?

Tags: opengl, 3d

I understand that glScalef(x,0,0) scales on X axis in both directions(+ve and -ve). But how to do the scaling in only one direction?(either +ve or -ve). And what coordinates should y and z have?(0 or 1) Throw some light on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
glTranslatef(x*0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glScalef(x, 1.0f, 1.0f);
drawObject();
```

treat this code like this: scale my object (x, 1, 1) then translate (x*0.5, 0, 0)... from bottom to top.

do not scale by 0! `glScalef(x, 0, 0)` will make your object dissapear!

look [here](http://what-when-how.com/opengl-programming-guide/viewing-and-modeling-transformations-opengl-programming-part-1/) and [here](http://what-when-how.com/opengl-programming-guide/viewing-and-modeling-transformations-opengl-programming-part-2/)

note that you are using old opengl and try to look for "modern" opengl tutorials.